# How can I find out the exact number of positive, negative or real roots of a single-variable polynomial equation?

Tags: polynomials

I know about Des Cartes' rule of signs. But that can't help very much find out the exact number of positive, negative or real roots of a single-variable polynomial equation. So my question is if there is any rule to find out the exact number.

Comment: Using Sturm's sequence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem you get the exact number (if you don't mind multiple roots).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but there are several numerical methods for finding a set of disjoint intervals of the real line such that each interval contains exactly one root of a given polynomial and their union contains all real roots of the polynomial. For an overview of these "real root isolation" methods see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-root_isolation).